# FFMPEG compilation errors

Tags: installation, troubleshooting, ffmpeg

First of all i am a newbie to Ubuntu Linux and have been trying to install and compile FFMPEG on an Ubuntu machine...
I am trying to compile FFMPEG on an Ubuntu machine, using the following link reference: https://ffmpeg.org/trac/ffmpeg/wiki/UbuntuCompilationGuide

I have already install git packages from resource centre whatever it results in search...
Whatever i am trying to clone to is showing the below error... and please note that the network is wireless and connected with full bandwidth and i am able to browse through website and not sure why its showing an error as unable to connect and connection timed out....

```
root@ubuntu:~# cd
root@ubuntu:~# git clone --depth 1 git://github.com/mstorsjo/fdk-aac.git
Cloning into 'fdk-aac'...
fatal: unable to connect to github.com:
github.com[0: 207.97.227.239]: errno=Connection timed out
```

Tried these commands as well to install x264 lib:

```
cd
git clone --depth 1 git://git.videolan.org/x264
cd x264
```

I am doing all this as a root user.

Any help and comments would be appreciated.

Thanks
Nitin

Comment: First of all, do you need to compile FFMPEG? There are precompiled packages available in the repos.
Second, you should not do anything as root user that doesn't require you to be logged in as root, because a single typo can make your system unable to boot. Download and compile as restricted user, only log in as root for the make install step.
Third: Check if internet is working. If the answer is yes, then it's probably a server error and might get fixed soon.

Comment: @soulsource Ubuntu no longer provides `ffmpeg` from the FFmpeg project.

Answer (score 2):

Some users experience issues connecting to Git servers due to network restrictions or firewalls on their end. The guide you are following also provides links to "source snapshots" as an alternative, and a link to the fdk-aac snapshot has just been added. The snapshots will provide recent code but you will have to download and extract each archive. Example using the link in the guide that states, "Note: You can download the nightly x264 source snapshot as an alternative to using git.":

```
wget ftp://ftp.videolan.org/pub/x264/snapshots/last_x264.tar.bz2
tar xjvf last_x264.tar.bz2
cd x264-snapshot-*
```

Then continue with the guide starting with the `./configure` line for the appropriate section.

Answer (score 1):

For most purposes, ffmpeg and avconv (the fork of ffmpeg included in the Ubuntu repositories) are interchangeable. Just install avconv, and when you're reading tutorials online, mentally replace every instance of 'ffmpeg' with 'avconv'.

Answer (score -2):

See the link below,

http://allofit.blog.com

This covers FFmpeg compilation on a step by step basis.

If you are having trouble cloning the git repos, try downloading the '**zip**' or '**tar.gz**' files provided by them instead.

Comment: Welcome to Ask Ubuntu! Whilst this may theoretically answer the question, [it would be preferable](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/8259) to include the essential parts of the answer here, and provide the link for reference.